# Chrome Dev Tools Timeline onClick Paint time

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome Dev tools to try and figure out how long it takes to display a hidden panel from the click event to paint. Using Chrome Dev tools I recorded from the time the user clicks the button, to when the hidden panel paints. In the attached image, the sequence is as follows: Event click 642ms + Update Layer Tree 44ms + paint 6.69ms.

[image]

In considering the performance that interaction seems slow compared to Google's RAIL model. I just wanted to know if I'm calculating this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation method seems correct. The goal is to measure the time between the user's action and the time at which the page shows a response to the user. So in this case, the start of the `click` event represents the user's action, and the end of the `Paint` activity represents the page's response.

You can also click+hold+drag to see how long that selection of the recording took.

[image: viewing duration of a part of a recording]

And yes, 600ms is slow in terms of the RAIL model's recommendation. Pages should respond in 100ms maximum. I.e. from the moment of the click, the page should paint in no more than 100ms.

Comment: Thanks for the info and tip!! Any suggestion as to why the onclick is so slow? Where should I look to see why this is so slow.

Comment: The flame chart in the **Main** section tells you exactly all of the activity that occurred during the click event. You should see a detailed log of JS calls (that info could be hidden, though). Take another screenshot of the entire **Main** section and I can provide more help.